zsh: command not found: deno
I have installed Deno on my macos. Here is my installation command and the install process:
myname@MacBook-Pro-2 ramda % curl -fsSL https://deno.land/install.sh | sh
######################################################################## 100.0%
Archive:  /Users/myname/.deno/bin/deno.zip
  inflating: /Users/myname/.deno/bin/deno
Deno was installed successfully to /Users/myname/.deno/bin/deno
Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.zshrc (or similar)
  export DENO_INSTALL="/Users/myname/.deno"
  export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
Run '/Users/myname/.deno/bin/deno --help' to get started

Stuck? Join our Discord https://discord.gg/deno
When I attempt to to run the demo: deno run --allow-net server.ts
I get zsh: command not found: deno
I have also tried running it in the actual directory where deno was installed
The installation appears to change the $PATH variable. I don't know why the command is not being found. Do I need to add the path to Deno manually?

did you follow the steps where it says Manually add the directory to.... ?


Do I need to add the path to Deno manually?

Yes.

Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.zshrc (or similar)
  export DENO_INSTALL="/Users/myname/.deno"
  export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"


That's what this line means.

Yes you are quite right. I missed that and assumed that Deno install has done that step. Thanks for kindly answering my question!

Resolved. I had to add deno path to my $PATH variable manually. Also when I used the fully qualified path to the command I missed an inital second / before the Users directory.

By the way, on Windows, don't forget to restart your computer
